# dividing a line segment in the ratio $1:2i$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The following exercise is from [Birkhoff and MacLane, A Survey of Modern Algebra]:

> Let $\alpha=(1,i,0), \beta=(0,1-i,2i)$.  Can you ``divide the line segment $\overline{\alpha \beta}$ in the ratio $1:2i$''? Explain.

We can consider the problem to be a generalization of the real case, where we just need to find a point $\gamma$ that is `between' $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the ratio of $\gamma - \alpha$ to $\beta - \gamma$ is 1 to $2i$.  In other words, we need to solve $(2i)(\gamma - \alpha) = (\beta-\gamma)$, which can of course be solved for $\gamma$.  Are there other interpretations or formulations?  Is there anything else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the equation you give, $(2i)(\gamma - \alpha) = (\beta-\gamma)$  After all, $\Bbb C$ is a field, so you can divide by anything that is not $0$.  The solution you get will not be on the segment $\overline{\alpha \beta}$.  "Explain" is not a mathematical term.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought.

Comment: Thanks for insight on "Explain", always makes one wonder what is a correct response to "Explain". Instead it should be "Make up an entertaining story"